# Проблема при работе с зеркальным объектом

Tags: blender

Когда начал делать отражение объекта с помощью модификатора Mirror — вторая половина отразилась совсем в другой части. Нужно сделать чтобы две части были вместе и получилась характерная фигура. Нужно, что бы получился амугус.

У меня сейчас:

[image: Картинка из блендера]

Должно быть:

[image: Что должно получиться]

Comment: Переместите центр объекта (object origin) в правильное место, видимо

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Как переместить центр объекта (object origin) в центр моей фигуры?

Comment: alt+ctrl+shift+c  
Geometry to Origin
Возможно это нужно сделать до модификатора mirror

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо переместить точку центра объекта в место, относительно которого будет производиться зеркальное отображение. В вашем случае необходимо в режиме редактирования для данного объекта выделить замкнутые связанные вершины, которые находятся в вашем будущем центре симметрии, с помощью Alt+LMB. Далее, вызвав меню Shift+S выбрать пункт Cursor to Selected. Перейти в объектный режим. Здесь, кликнув RMB, выбрать пункт Set Origin -> Origin to 3D Cursor. Таким образом центр объекта будет смещён в нужное вам место - центр симметрии объекта. Уже в модификаторе Mirror также можете отметить пункт Clipping для объединения вершин, которые сходятся в одной точке.